# HTML table with horizontal scrolling (four columns fixed)

Tags: css, html-table

I've been struggling to create a table where the first four columns are fixed, whereas the rest of them have a horizontal scrolling. I found this example [first column fixed](http://jsbin.com/qeheceqiyo/edit?html,css,output)

It has the first column fixed. I am very new to CSS and cannot extend to make the four first columns fixed. Any one could help? Sorry, that should be very simple, I just can't.

Comment: provide your own code and what you have tried so far in order to get efficient help :)

Comment: I've tried using two table. One float on the left side of the other! Because it is now very aligned I searched for a single table solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS:

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed; 
  width: 100%;
  *margin-left: -100px;/*ie7*/
}
td, th {
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding:10px;
  width:100px;
}
.col1{
  position:absolute;
  *position: relative; /*ie7*/
  left:0; 
  width:100px;
}
.col2{
  position:absolute;
  *position: relative; /*ie7*/
  left:100px; 
  width:100px;
}
.col3{
  position:absolute;
  *position: relative; /*ie7*/
  left:200px; 
  width:100px;
}
.col4{
  position:absolute;
  *position: relative; /*ie7*/
  left:300px; 
  width:100px;
}
.outer {position:relative}
.inner {
  overflow-x:scroll;
  overflow-y:visible;
  width:500px; 
  margin-left:400px;
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <table>
        <tr>
          <th class="col1">Header A</th>
           <th class="col2">Header A</th>
             <th class="col3">Header A</th>
                <th class="col4">Header A</th>

          <td>col 2 - A (WITH LONGER CONTENT)</td>
          <td>col 3 - A</td>
          <td>col 4 - A</td>
          <td>col 5 - A</td>
           <td>col 6 - B</td>
          <td>col 7 - B</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <th class="col1">Header B</th>
            <th class="col2">Header B</th>
              <th class="col3">Header B</th>
                <th class="col4">Header B</th>

          <td>col 2 - B</td>
          <td>col 3 - B</td>
          <td>col 4 - B</td>
          <td>col 5 - B</td>
            <td>col 6 - B</td>
          <td>col 7 - B</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <th class="col1">Header C</th>
            <th class="col2">Header C</th>
               <th class="col3">Header C</th>
                <th class="col4">Header C</th>

          <td>col 2 - C</td>
          <td>col 3 - C</td>
          <td>col 4 - C</td>
          <td>col 5 - C</td>
           <td>col 6 - B</td>
          <td>col 7 - B</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h75zn59o/

Position:absolute; is what causes that first header column to be fixed. With the original CSS, it's just applied to "th",  but using classes (in this example, col1, col2, etc.) we can assign different fixed positions to different columns. Because the columns are 100px wide, each following column is positioned another 100px left So, the first one is 0px, then 100px for col2, etc) to avoid overlap with the previous column.

Answer (score 1):

Assign some class to the `td` tags you want scrollable and add overflow-x:scroll

Comment: I wrapped all td tags with a div containing a class called 'test'. It doesn't work! If I put a test tag to each of the tds, each one of them will scroll!! Still doesn't work.